# Serving page data from solr/elasticsearch

Tags: mysql, database, solr, elasticsearch

I'm using Solr (might move to Elasticsearch) to index documents that users can search. The data comes from MySQL, which takes writes from users. Each search result can be clicked to view it's details, as is common. The details page fetches all the data from MySQL.

Since several of the fields that the details page displays are already being indexed in Solr, would it be better to simply store all the fields in Solr and simply not hit the database? The details page already has to query Solr for more-like-this suggestions.

I'm sure that for now it won't be an issue either way. But what do most medium or high traffic websites do? Examples of websites that have similar functionality would be newspapers. Stackoverflow itself is somewhat different since the data is more dynamic as users can keep adding replies to questions.

I actually never even though of serving the data from Solr until recently, when I decided to add a feature whose implementation would be simpler if the data is served from Solr rather than MySQL, but I have no idea whether this is a good idea or not.

What do you guys think? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solr/Elasticsearch support this feature. There are two kinds of fields in Solr/ES - Indexed and Stored.

Indexed fields are the ones which are searched against - these produce the matches. Stored fields on the other hand are just container.

It is quite common (at least in my experience) to store non-indexed values as stored fields in a Solr document. This helps save a roundtrip to the data store to get detail results.

You could mark a field as both Stored and Indexed if you want to have search and display feature.

Why not Index everything, you may ask? Because, indexed fields contribute to index size which eats up disk space, besides increasing the index time.

So, I would encourage to use Solr as a data store (unless you have ton of non-indexed data per document). As mentioned above, choose your index wisely, and you will gain by saving repeated db calls.

Comment: I am indeed using stored fields already. However, they are used to display information about search results _along_ with the results, rather than in a different page that is linked from the search results. For instance, typically you'll want to display the entire title of each document in the page containing search results, for which you need to use a stored field for the title. However, when the user clicks on the title to go to the "details" page, the stored field can't be utilized directly i.e. a round-trip is unavoidable.

Comment: Well- that use case requires an explicit round-trip. If you are already using stored fields, then I guess expanding the number of stored fields is only going to eat up disk space. What I would look out for is - Solr becoming a persistent data store, which can be a bit dangerous I'd say.